# AngularJS Expression with MVC Razor @section

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, sections

I am trying to do something that seemed simple to me but somehow does not want to work. It's the following:

I set a background on my Layout page as such:

```
<img class="background" @RenderSection("backgroundimage", required: false)/>
```

And on my body page it takes the src as such:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cds">
   @section backgroundimage{ src="http://{{item.urlfromdb}}.jpg"}
</div>
```

But apparently the two don't want to work together. Is there a way to get the Angular Expression inside the @section?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right you are trying to do impossible thing;
Razor lives only on a server side. 
And Angular lives only in browser scope. 
So, Angular can use Razor's result but razor, cant (in a simple way) result of Angular.

In your case, your @section operator will render smth, before Angular can evaluate your expression {{item.urlfromdb}}

But. You can use razor to get this prop from your model on a server side.

Comment: ok i understand, however you write can't in a simple way. What would be the difficult way? Do you have an example perhaps?

Comment: My first idea was to use smth like serverside rendering (https://www.quora.com/What-is-client-and-server-side-rendering-and-how-it-is-related-to-single-page-applications) But now I think that cant solve your problem. Possibly you should look to use model or viewData